# Enums as key in Spark PairRDD's causing problems

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, enums

Some operation's on Spark `PairRDD`'s don't work correctly when the RDD's key is or contains an enum.

For example, the following piece of Spark code takes two weeks worth of weekdays and counts them, by weekday:

```scala
import java.time.DayOfWeek
val weekdays: Seq[(DayOfWeek, Int)] = DayOfWeek.values().map(dow => (dow, 1))
val numPartitions = 2 * weekdays.size
val result = sc
  .parallelize(weekdays ++ weekdays, numPartitions)
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .collect
  .toSeq
println(result)
```

In the output, I'd expect every weekday (e.g., `MONDAY`) to have count 2, however, on my cluster, I get:

```
WrappedArray(
  (THURSDAY,1), (SATURDAY,1), (WEDNESDAY,2), (SATURDAY,1),
  (MONDAY,2), (TUESDAY,2), (THURSDAY,1), (FRIDAY,2), (SUNDAY,2)
)
```

If you run this on a cluster with a single node (or set `numPartitions` to 1), the result is correct (i.e., all counts are 2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark `PairRDD`'s operations like `aggregateByKey()`, `reduceByKey()`, `combineByKey()` take an optional argument to specify the [`Partitioner`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.html) that Spark is to use. If you don't specify a partitioner explicitly, Spark's `HashPartitioner` is used, which calls a row's key's [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) method and uses it to assign the row to a partition. However, the `hashCode()` of an enum is not guaranteed to be the same on different JVMs processes – even if they run on the same Java version. As a consequence, Spark `xyzByKey()` operations don't work correctly.

In the above example, there are two pairs `(THURSDAY, 1)` in the input and each gets processed on a different executor. The example uses a `HashPartitioner` with 14 (= `numPartitions`) partitions. Since `(THURSDAY, 1).hashCode() % 14` produces different results on these two executors, these two rows get sent to different executors to be reduced, resulting in an incorrect result.

**Bottomline:** Don't use `HashPartitioner` with objects whose hashcode's aren't consistent over different JVM processes. In particular, the following objects aren't guaranteed to produce the same hashcode on different JVM processes:

- Java `enum`'s
- Scala `sealed trait`-based enum's:

```scala
sealed trait TraitEnum
object TEA extends TraitEnum
object TEB extends TraitEnum
```

- Scala `abstract class`-based enum's:

```scala
sealed abstract class AbstractClassEnum
object ACA extends AbstractClassEnum
object ACB extends AbstractClassEnum
```

- Any key that contains a nested object of one of the above types (and doesn't have a custom `hashCode()` implementation).

However, Scala `case class`-based enum's, have a consistent hashcode and are thus safe to use:

```scala
sealed case class CaseClassEnum(…) # “…" must be a non-empty list of parameters
object CCA extends CaseClassEnum(…)
object CCB extends CaseClassEnum(…)
```

**Additional info:**

- Blog post: http://dev.bizo.com/2014/02/beware-enums-in-spark.html
- [Ticket on Spark with a proposal to catch this at compile/runtime](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3847)